# Subtraction days (impala)

Tags: sql, impala

Can you please tell me how to display lines where 'date' minus two days from today's date. And how then to change the data type of string. The 'date' column is in YYYYMMDD format.

Why is this query not working?

```
select * from table where 'date'= cast(subdate(current_date(), 2 days) as string)
```

Answer (score 0):

use below

```
select * from table where `date`=  from_timestamp(now() - interval 2 days,'yyyyMMdd')
```

`from_timestamp(timestamp_data, 'yyyyMMdd')`  - This converts a date to a desired string format.
`-interval 2 days`  - This takes date time back to 2days before system date.